# Asymptote 3D label background

Tags: asymptote

I'd like to create a 3D label in Asymptote that has a "background," effectively giving the label the look as though it were printed on poster board. I don't care if this background conforms to the Billboard effect when the 3D image is rotated; my only need here is for a static picture. I need the label to stand out against the surface behind it.

I know I could fake it by placing a white plane behind my label, but I don't know how to form this plane properly - how to correctly find the normal of the plane so that it looks rectangular from the viewpoint.

Here's a MWE, wherein the text of the label gets a little "lost" in the lines of the surface behind it.

```
import graph3;
size(200,200,IgnoreAspect);
currentprojection=orthographic(5,5,1);
defaultrender.merge=true;

triple f(pair t) {
    return (t.y*cos(t.x),2*t.y*sin(t.x),t.y);//
}
surface s=surface(f,(0,0),(2*pi,2),32,32,Spline);
draw(s,emissive(white),meshpen=black+.2mm);

label("plot of $x$",(2,2,1.5));
```

I use TikZ for some of my graphics, and there it is a simple manner to have the node drawn with a solid background color making the text easy to read. I am basically looking for the same effect here.

Comment: Please provide `MWE` of the scene with labels 
for which you'd like to add a background.

Comment: I once spent some hours trying to figure out how to do this. I'm sure it's possible, but in the end I just positioned the white plane by trial and error. In so doing, I discovered that the effect was not nearly as nice as I had hoped--for some reason, this effect just does not look good in 3d.

Comment: That having been said, it would still be good to have a "right" solution, even if the effect is much less useful than one might assume.

Comment: @g.kov   I have added a MWE for you.

Comment: @CharlesStaats If you have tried it, and were not so successful, I probably won't spend much more time on it. Manually adjusting corners of a box in 3D seems like a big pain... if I really need the effect, I might go that route.

Comment: One dimension is easy (use `-currentprojection.camera` if your projection is orthogonal for the direction away from the camera), so it's really just a question of sizing the box. But it is still a bit of a pain.

Comment: Nit: `defaultrender.merge` only affects prc rendering. Since you want a static picture, you don't need to set it.

Comment: @CharlesStaats  I did figure out the normal vector bit, but getting the corners of the plane looks like lots of trial and error. I thought of getting very mathematical and rotating/shifting a rectangle from the x,y plane to the correct spot, but the work involved isn't worth it to me at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution is slightly hacky, but much less draconian than drawing on top of the picture. It creates two labels: one with the text, and one, positioned directly behind the text (relative to the camera), with a solid box the same size as the text. This solution will only work if the projection is orthographic.

```
settings.outformat="png";
settings.render=4;
import graph3;
usepackage("color");
size(200,200,IgnoreAspect);
currentprojection=orthographic(5,5,1);

// Decreasing the tubegranularity makes the gridlines look nicer.
defaultrender.tubegranularity = 1e-3;

triple forward = -unit(currentprojection.camera);
// Take the component of currentprojection.up orthogonal to forward.
triple upvec = unit(currentprojection.up - dot(currentprojection.up,forward) * forward);
triple rightvec = cross(forward, upvec);

triple f(pair t) {
    return (t.y*cos(t.x),2*t.y*sin(t.x),t.y);
}
surface s=surface(f,(0,0),(2*pi,2),32,32,Spline);
draw(s,emissive(white),meshpen=black+.2mm);

label("plot of $x$", (2,2,1.5));
label("\colorbox{black}{plot of $x$}", (2,2,1.5) + .01 forward, white+opacity(0.9));
```

[image: cone labeled plot of x]

Comment: Nice. I was able to make something near this, but didn't know that I could add "white" to the end of the label to turn the black box from the `\colorbox{}{}` white. I'm continually amazed by the number of options/settings that exist; I knew nothing of `tube.granularity`. Finally, just to be clear, you might remove `upvec` and `rightvec` from your answer as you don't actually use them.

Comment: I only just found out about `tube.granularity` myself--see http://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/bugs/191/#e4f7

Comment: Concerning `upvec` and `rightvec`: They will come in handy if you want to move anything in the left/right or up/down directions. But you are correct that I did not end up using them here.

Comment: Nice thinking ahead ...

Answer (score 4):

Following the answer from [asymptote discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/0e7bb5d2/),

```
//
// bglabel3d.asy
//
settings.tex="pdflatex";
settings.prc=false;
settings.render=0;

import graph3;
size(200,200,IgnoreAspect);
currentprojection=orthographic(5,5,1);
defaultrender.merge=true;

triple f(pair t) { return (t.y*cos(t.x),2*t.y*sin(t.x),t.y); }

surface s=surface(f,(0,0),(2*pi,2),32,32,Spline);
draw(s,emissive(white),meshpen=deepblue+.2mm);

label(Label("plot of $x$",Fill(orange+opacity(0.8))),(2,2,1.5));
```

[image]

**Edit**:

As it is noted in the 
linked answer, this solution works 
only with `render=0`.

For raster images we can 
[draw the labels on the image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz/129801#129801):

First, make a label-free `img.png`:

```
//
// scene3d.asy
//
settings.outformat="png";
settings.prc=false;
settings.render=4;
import graph3;
size(200,200,IgnoreAspect);
currentprojection=orthographic(5,5,1);
defaultrender.merge=true;

triple f(pair t) { return (t.y*cos(t.x),2*t.y*sin(t.x),t.y); }

surface s=surface(f,(0,0),(2*pi,2),32,32,Spline);

pen bpen=rgb(0.75, 0.7, 0.1);
material m=material(diffusepen=0.6bpen
  ,ambientpen=bpen
  ,emissivepen=0.4*bpen
  ,specularpen=0.8white
  ,shininess=1.0);
draw(s,m);
shipout("img");
```

next, draw the labels on the raster image:

```
settings.tex="pdflatex";
import graph;
import math; // for grid() function

defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));

real sc=1/4;
unitsize(sc*1bp);

real wd=796*sc;
real ht=808*sc;

label(
  shift(wd/2,ht/2)*
  graphic("img.png"
  ,"width="+string(wd)+"bp"
  +",height="+string(ht)+"bp"
  +",scale="+string(sc)
  ),(0,0)
);
layer();

draw(((0,0)--(wd,ht)/sc),blue+2pt);

int ngrid=100;
int n=(int)(wd/(ngrid-1)/sc);
int m=(int)(ht/(ngrid-1)/sc);
add(scale(ngrid)*grid(n,m,yellow));

xaxis( 0,wd/sc,RightTicks(Step=ngrid));
yaxis(0,ht/sc,LeftTicks(Step=ngrid));


label(Label("plot of $y$"
    ,Fill(1mm,orange+opacity(0.8))),(400,400));
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about nesting `label` and `Label` commands. It is interesting that adding extra space to the text of the label doesn't seem to affect the size of the colored box. Adding `\phantom{xx}`, for instance, does nothing.

Comment: @GregH: Yes, the label is trimmed to fit the actual ink,
but we can use a trick with microscopic dot:
`\rule{1sp}{1sp}\phantom{xx}plot of $x$`.
Also, the first parameter to `Fill` can be used
to enlarge the bounding box,
for example, `Fill(5mm,orange+opacity(0.8)))`.

Comment: This is great, but it does not seem to work when `settings.render > 0`.

Comment: I realized that after marking the solution as "the" answer. While I like the vector based graphics of `settings.render=0`, it doesn't seem to handle multiple objects well. In the cone above, it works fine. For most of my pictures it doesn't. So I still want to see a solution that works for any render setting.